# contents-immutable and locking the Dock

Tags: macos, dock, preferences

I have the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock contents-immutable -bool yes
defaults write com.apple.Dock size-immutable -bool yes
defaults write com.apple.Dock position-immutable -bool yes
```

I can run them fine from the Admin account and it works, but is there a way to do this on a non-admin account? Even Sudo did not seem to work exactly.

Can I just do a chattr +i? what is the immutable string actually doing in the background?

This is running 10.9.x

Answer (score 1):

The property list you are referring to is com.apple.dock.plist. Try using com.apple.dock as the domain.

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by using that as a domain?

Comment: @Frank Sorry, the arguments for the defaults command are `write <domain> <key> <value>` so I meant `defaults write com.apple.dock …` (with a lower case d). For more context, see the trouble when Apple renamed com.apple.Finder to com.apple.finder.

Comment: At least as far back as OS X 10.8 (and possibly earlier), the case of the domain makes no difference. `defaults read com.apple.dock` is the same as `defaults read COM.Apple.Dock`